# The gcc System call: Redirecting console output to new terminal window

Tags: c, linux, gcc

So here is the source code for a program that enumerates the first 13 Fibonacci numbers. When I run it, it opens a new terminal window but does not print the output in the new terminal. It prints it out in the terminal window that I typed the execution command. What's going wrong here? How do I print the output in the newly spawned terminal window?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

int  Fibonacci(unsigned int n);

int main()
{
  int exit_status = system("gnome-terminal");

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 13 ; i++) {
       printf("\n");
       printf("%u\n",Fibonacci(i));      
  }
}

int Fibonacci(unsigned int n)
{
  if(n==0) {
    return 0;
  } else if(n==1) {
    return 1;
  } else if(n>1) {
    return Fibonacci(n-2)+Fibonacci(n-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Launch a new window to display your results?

Comment: For this to work, you have to 1) execute the `gnome-terminal` process; 2) find the shell TTY point (e.g.: `pts/3`); 3) open `/dev/pts/3` in write mode using `fprintf` and 4) output your data to the created handle. It's not as simple as `system` and `printf`.

Comment: Yes Linuxios, that is precisely what I'm trying to do.

Comment: How do you execute the gnome-terminal process using C code?